# Tor Browser not launching Ubuntu

Tags: browser, tor

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and Tor Browser not launching (Error 404...) I read a few post but I had have no succes.

But  if I go to the  terminal and type

```
cd /home/username/Downloads/tor-browser-linux64-12.0.6_ALL/tor-browser
```

and type

```
 ./start-tor-browser.desktop --verbose
```

then Tor-Browser works. Every time I start my system, I must do  the same in this way. Some body knows what is happen?

Comment: The Tor Browser Launcher tool in the repository for 22.04 and other versions of Ubuntu is not functional at the moment, and a patch set needs to be applied to those packages to work.  Until then, the launcher will not be functional and this is a known bug.